# os.walk() returns None although there are files present

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a function that should read the filenames in a directory using os.walk. The directory variable is the pathname in full.
Although there are files present, the output is none.

```
def list_files(directory):
    file_list = []
    for _ ,_ , files in os.walk(directory):
       for name in files:
           file_list.append(name)
       return file_list
```

trying with dirs  `for _ ,dirs, _ in os.walk(directory):` instead of files also gives the same result: None, also when there are folders in the path

Comment: The `return` statement is inside the outer for-loop. Should it be outside both loops?

Comment: @slothrop for return inside the outer loop, the result is [] and None for return outside the outer loop

Comment: That seems impossible: `file_list` is initialised to `[]` in the first statement of the function and there's no way with this code that it can become `None`.

Comment: my bad, its None because I used `str(file_list)`. Else its just blankspace

Comment: Can you try running your code on a mockup directory containing a couple of test files, and describe for us the contents of this directory and the results you're obtaining?

Comment: @slothrop The function shown in the question **could** return None. It will do so, implicitly, if *directory* doesn't exist or is empty

Comment: @DarkKnight *as written*, yes it could. But OP had said that the result was None *if the return was moved outside the outer loop*, and that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: A different function (to get the directory path) had malfunctioned and subsequently led to this not working properly. Its all good now. `return` should be outside the loops as @slothrop pointed out